# Java casting in wrapper Number classes

Tags: java, casting, wrapper, long-integer, primitive

Why it's correct:

```
Long l = new Long(10);
```

but it's not correct:

```
Long l2 = 10;
```

I understand that int is substituted here, but why is `new Long(10)` correct?

Comment: `10` is an `int` (`10L` would be a `long`). And an `int` doesn't get boxed into a `Long`. Boxing `10` to `Integer` doesn't make it a `Long`, because an `Integer` is **not** a `Long`.

Comment: The constructor of `Long` takes a `long`, which the `int` can be converted to. In the second example, a `int` or the autoboxed `Integer` can not be assigned to a `Long` though. You can use a `long` literal to make it work, use `Long l2 = 10L;`.